# Load in a specific name in combobox as first row

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

i have a model with an id and a name.
[I put the model object into a combobox. From the model i take the name atribute and make that the visual part, the only problem is. When you start up the](https://i.stack.imgur.com/incFX.png) program the combobox it is empty.
You have to click on it and select the second row to see the item. I would like to see the item straight away. is this possible?

```
public class ItemCell extends ListCell<Model> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Model person, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(person, empty);
        setText(person == null ? "" : person.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

in my view class i have:

```
ComboBox<Model> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new ItemCell());
comboBox.setButtonCell(new ItemCell());
comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      personModelFromCombobox = otherObject.getPerson();
});
```

as you see it does everything correct except you have to click on it and select the second row to see the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because you do not select an item in the `comboBox`

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(index);
```

where `index` is the [integer position](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html#select-int-) of the item to select in the selection model, or a [value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html#select-T-) from and of the same type as the arrayList.